# Usage of existing Nginx installation with GitLab doesn't work

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I am trying to configure a GitLab installation to work on a subdomain with an existing Nginx installation.

Current state is:

- gitlab.my.example.com is not working
- my.example.com is also not working
- `x.x.x.x` (IP) is working, displaying the welcome page of nginx

Nginx and GitLab are both running.

Steps I did:

- Installed Nginx
- Installed Ruby and Passenger
- Installed Gitlab-EE
- Configured it like it is written down [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passenger-nginx-installation).

OS is Debian 8.

Does someone maybe know where I should look for the error or tell me what is needed to help me to solve the problem?

Best regards

Comment: check `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` what it says when You navigate ещ your host in browser

Comment: This looks in my opinion alright. When I am navigating it, it doesn't append anything. https://pastebin.com/1jh0gwdR

What I am suspecting sometimes is that the ports or configs are maybe false.

Comment: What does "not work" means? Does it respond to these sudbdomains, do they give you error and if so what?
My guess you have blindly copy/pasted that config and didn't bother to check the paths or any of the settings.